# Two entries for Google Chrome in Notifications preferences

Tags: macos, google-chrome, notifications, preferences

In System Preferences > Notifications, there are two entries for Google Chrome, and they have different settings.

[image]

[image]

I can obviously change them both to what I want, but why is this happening and how can I get rid of the extra one?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**The new answer**

The reason why you see two notification sections in System preferences is because one is for calendar (That is the one with the banner) and one regular notifications (the one that controls website notifications

---

**The old answer**
The reason why this answer is not right in your cause is because this is for Chrome's settings

If you have multiple accounts on your Google Chrome browser, you can change the notifications for both accounts. If you want to get rid of a Google Chrome notification panel, simply get rid of the account that you are not using anymore. The reason why they have different settings is that the primary account will show up different then your other accounts.

Comment: The "People" menu only shows one account. Could the other notification panel be for the built-in "Guest" account?

Comment: Is there any way to tell which setting is for which account?

Comment: Oh wait, that is the wrong notification panel. Let me edit my answer real quick

Comment: The answer I gave was what you see in Google Chrome.

Comment: I just trashed the Google Chrome and rechecked this Notifications & Events, yet now there is only ONE Google Chrome showing.

Comment: That was on Monterey macOS now in 2021.  Reinstalling with a newer Google Chrome seems to have 'reclaimed' that lone Chrome entry in 'Noitifications & Focus', so all is good.

Answer (score 1):

For Monterey release of macOS in 2021 (4 years later), trashing the Google Chrome app and downloading a new Chrome from [here](https://www.google.com/intl/en_us/chrome/) seems to fix this problem.

New Google Chrome has reclaimed the old 'Notification & Focus' entry (or at least deleted the old one and installed just ONE entry).

Answer (score 0):

From [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/pqlxjo/chrome_appearing_twice_under_notifications_anyone/) on the same topic, the answer was *intuitively obvious* ...

> Have you tried deleting one or both entries (just select entry and hit Backspace key)?
>
> Notification to (re-)enable notifications :) should appear after next Chrome restart.

Back to just the one entry now.

Comment: The duplicate is gone in Ventura. Now the second one is called Google Chrome Helper (Alerts). I suspect this is what the old duplicate was, it just didn't have a distinct name.

Comment: I'm still on Monterey for now but thanks for the update. Only saw the duplicate because something had enabled persistent alerts for GCal